# Why is the required form not submitting?

Tags: html, forms, label

I am making a required form for my web development course but I seem to be stuck. I copied the course's code word for word and I'm not sure if it's a browser issue? Whenever I hit the register button, the only required field that works is the first name. It says "Please Fill out the Field." The last name field, the email field, and the password field do not say that even though I put required next to them. What am I doing wrong? Any answers would be helpful! I've been stuck on this for hours haha. I tried putting a form action in between each paragraph but that stopped the form from submitting the required text completely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Race Registration!</h1>
    <form action="/race_registration">
        <p>
            <iabel for="first">First name</iabel>
            <input type="text" id="first" name="firstname" required>
            <iabel for="last">Last name</iabel>
            <input type="text" id="last" name="lastname" required>
        </p>
        <p>

            <label for="select race">Select a Race:</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="race" id="Fun Run" value="fun run">
            <label for="Fun Run">Fun Run 5k</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="race" id="Half value=" half">
            <label for="half">Half Marathon</label>

        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="race" id="Full" value="full">
            <label for="Full">Full Marathon</label>

        </p>
        <p>
            <iabel for="email">Email</iabel>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="division">Select Age Group</label>
            <select name="division" id="division">
                <option value="kids">Under 18</option>
                <option value="ya">18-30</option>
                <option value="adults">30-50</option>
                <option value="senior">50+</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <button>Register</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works if you remove the `type="email"` and `type="password"` attributes from the `email` and `password` fields respectively. However, I'm guessing you probably don't want to remove them. In that case, you have to resort to JavaScript-based form validation.